# Perform some operation inside Select statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Controller action method which returns  `IQueryable<AnswerDTO >`  which has a field named "Sequence". I want to set this field after some calculation. My approach is

```
var answer = from dfi in _db.DiaryFormInstances
 //Some Query with LINQ
 select new AnswerDTO()
 {
     Value = dfit.Value,
     //How to perform this operation?
     Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(fti.ItemName.Substring(fti.ItemName.LastIndexOf("_")+1)),
     LastModifiedDate = dfit.LastModifiedDate.Value,
     LastModifiedByID = dfit.LastModifiedByID.Value
 };
```

How to set Sequence property like this inside select statement?

```
Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(fti.ItemName.Substring(fti.ItemName.LastIndexOf("_")+1))
```

If I execute the query in my action method then I can easily perform this operation. But I want to return IQueryable, and I do not want to execute query inside my action method.

I want web api will execute the query and after execute it will set Sequence property properly.

Comment: I see `dfi` defined in the query but not used in the select statement whereas `dfit` and `fti` are used but are not defined

Comment: Emdadul, I've added another more robust answer that I've tested in a small application on my machine. I removed my previous answer as it turns out the functions needed were not available in Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the functions available in Linq to Entities it seems that extracting the number in the way you wish is not possible with what's built in.

Your best bet is to create a custom function in the DB that you can call. To do this, first create the following function in your database (you can create it directly using SSMS for example):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ExtractSequence
(
    @sequenceString NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(RIGHT(@sequenceString, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE('_' + @sequenceString)) - 1) AS INT)
END
GO
```

Next you will need to include the https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/ package, it's on NuGet, just search for `CodeFirstStoreFunctions`.

Once you've added the above package you'll need to add `modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention("dbo", this.GetType()));` to the `OnModelCreating` method of your context class, e.g.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention("dbo", this.GetType()));
}
```

Next you need to add the following to the context class as well:

```
// First parameter should always be CodeFirstDatabaseSchema, this is just a convention used by the store functions package
// The second parameter should match the name of the function in the DB. You can call the method something else but I'd keep it the same as the function name too
[DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "ExtractSequence")]
public static int ExtractSequence(string sequenceString)
{
    // No need to provide an implementation as this is like a placeholder for the DB function you created in the DB in the first step
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Finally, you can use the new function in your Linq to Entity expressions, so you'd change your select to look something like:

```
var answer = from dfi in _db.DiaryFormInstances
select new AnswerDTO()
{
    Value = dfit.Value,
    Sequence = MyDbContext.ExtractSequence(fti.ItemName), // Change MyDbContext to whatever your context class is
    LastModifiedDate = dfit.LastModifiedDate.Value,
    LastModifiedByID = dfit.LastModifiedByID.Value
};
```